# vbs scheduled path not found

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I have a batch file starting a vbs script.
The script just makes some operations in some files, like moving them, create, delete... 
It works fine. 
Executing the bat it starts the vbs script and everything work.
The bat file just makes a cscript file.vbs

The problem is that I've scheduled this bat file .
When the times come, it gets executed but I get the error "path not found" in the vbs script.

It's not a schedule task problem because I've 11 task running batch files and they run smootly, and the script is executed (I've put controllers on it).
But the vbs script returns always the same path not found error.

Again,if I execute the script manually, it runs without problems.

The task is scheduled with the same account I use to manual execute the file, so it's not a permission issue. I just doubleclick the batch and it runs, click on execute on the task schedule manager and it fails.

The system is windows server 2008 r2 standard.
I already tried to reboot, deleting and making a new task....

Thanks to everyone

[UPDATE]

I paste here part of the code

FILE: D:\scripts\conf.ini

```
[script1]
    fileA=D:\Rep\exportA.csv
    fileB=D:\Rep\exportB.csv
    fileC=D:\Rep\exportC.csv
    dirHistory=D:\Rep\history
```

FILE: D:\scripts\merge.vbs

```
Dim iniObj
Set iniObj=New ClsINI
If iniObj.OpenINIFile("D:\scripts\conf.ini") = False Then
    wLog("Impossible to read file ini")
    Set iniObj = Nothing
    Chiudi()
End If
Dim errIni,tmpVal
Dim fileA,fileB,fileC,dirHistory

errIni = iniObj.GetINIValue("script1", "fileA", fileA)
tmpVal = iniObj.GetINIValue("script1", "fileB", fileB)
errIni = errIni+tmpVal
tmpVal = iniObj.GetINIValue("script1", "fileC", fileC)
errIni = errIni+tmpVal
tmpVal = iniObj.GetINIValue("script1", "dirHistory", dirHistory)
errIni = errIni+tmpVal

If errIni > 0 Then
    wLog("Error loading file ini")
    wLog(errIni)
    iniObj.CloseINIFile()
    Set iniObj = Nothing
    Chiudi()
End If

wLog("File ini Caricato")

Dim objFso,posizioneFile,Fase
Dim arrElement,resArray,actionArray,cedoleArray,varArray ,i
Dim conn,rs,strCon
Dim maxPos,maxTemp
Dim objExcel, objSheet,cella

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if objFso.FileExists(fileA) then
    objFso.DeleteFile(posizione)
    wLog("File posizione moved")
else
    wLog("File posizione not found")
end if
```

At this line a get the error of "Path not found"

```
Set posizioneFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(fileA, 8, True)

If not objFso.FileExists(fileB) then
    SendEmail("nego")
    Fase=false
Else
    Set tFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(fileB, 1)
    strFile=tFile.ReadAll

    tFile.Close
    posizioneFile.WriteLine strFile
    objFso.MoveFile fileB, dirHistory&"\Negoz_"& CreaId(2) & ".csv"
End If
posizioneFile.Close
```

FILE: D:\scripts\merge.bat

```
echo Start Merge %date% %time% >> Started.log
cscript D:\scripts\merge.vbs
```

Sorry if I didn't put it before, but I was thinking it was a windows issue, because I thought the code was fine.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `fileA` when you get that error? Add a line `WScript.Echo fileA` before the line that raises the error and check if a) you get an absolute path and b) the path exists. If you get a relative path, check the working directory (`WScript.Echo objFso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")`) if the path exists inside it.

Comment: I've already tryed to echo the variable value, and it shows the right absolute path, and it exists. I've tryed to debug all I could, but everything seems fine. I've even tryed to make another batch executing the merge.bat. And it works. But once scheduled it returns the error. I was thinking to rewrite everything in python, but don't like to leave unresolved things and there are 800 rows of code to convert...

Comment: Double-check that by inserting a line `WScript.Echo objFso.FileExists(fileA) : WScript.Echo objFso.FolderExists(objFso.GetParentFolderName(fileA))`. Also double-check that `fileA` contains an actual file name (i.e. does not have a trailing ``\``).

Comment: I made a triple check. The result: execute from scheduled task, FileExists return 0, GetParentFolderName return 0, Set posizioneFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(fileA, 8, True) runtime error: path not found. merge.bat executed manually: FileExists return 0, GetParent returns -1, Set posizioneFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(fileA, 8, True) actually creates the file in the right place. I have no clue!!

Comment: Does the scheduled task run under a different user account? Is the path local or on a network share?

Comment: I've checked this as well... The task is executed under user in administrators group, the same I make manual tests. The vbs is local, but the fileA is on a network share. But I have group policy creating the networks share map, and I made the map permanent. Futhermore I try executing the task by execute action in schedule window (so when I'm logged in with that user, with the network shares active and son on). I don't understand what happens. Before it was working and suddenly I get this error.

Comment: One last thing I'd try is delete and re-create the scheduled task. If that still doesn't fix the problem I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: :) sorry to say, but iI have already tryed that way. Deleted and created as new one twice. I try all I can imagine and search before asking for help. But this lett me really clueless. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the question over at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). Your problem is with the system, not with your code, so you're more likely to get help there. Just make sure to state what you already have tried in your question. It's not good style to let other people waste their time on things you already checked.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with the working directory although it's a bit difficult to tell, since you chose not to show the content of the batch script. If you start the script manually (by double-clicking), the working directory is the directory in which the batch script (and probably the VBScript as well) resides. If you run the batch script as a scheduled task, the working directory is `%SystemRoot%\system32` unless you expressly set a working directory in the task's properties.

Now, if your batch script looks like this:

```
cscript.exe your.vbs
```

it will look for `your.vbs` in the working directory and won't find it if the working directory is not the directory containing `your.vbs`. If my assumption that both scripts are in the same directory is correct you could either set the working directory in the properties of the scheduled task or (better) change the batch script to something like this:

```
cscript.exe "%~dp0your.vbs"
```

`%0` is the path to the batch script itself as it was called. `%~dp0` expands `%0` to the absolute path of the parent directory (including a trailing backslash).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I didn't show the batch file because it is just echo date >> activate.log and cscript file.vbs. I have set up the working directory in task schedule and the error is not in the batch, but in the vbs. The batch starts normally and it executes the vbs, but it is the path in vbs that is not found

Comment: Please update your question with the (VBScript) code. We're not playing guessing games here.